# Remove specific tag from xml using regex without removing data after tag

Tags: python, regex

I have an XML with some mismatched tags `ENAMEX` that I am attempting to remove

```
<Subject stype="ORG" xref="1234">
    <SubjectFullName type="L"><ENAMEX type="ORGANIZATION" id="ORG-112233-000">WEBSITE.COM</SubjectFullName>
    <SubjectLastName type="L">WEBSITE.COM</ENAMEX></SubjectLastName>
    <SubjectPhone type="Work">1234567890</SubjectPhone>
</Subject>
```

I have attempted the following code

```
mm = 'ENAMEX'
extra_tag_search = f"</{mm}><"
add_closing_tag_search = f"<{mm}(?!.*</{mm}>)(.*)"
add_closing_tag_replace = f"<{mm}>\1</{mm}>" 
ffx = re.sub(extra_tag_search, "<", ff)
fff = re.sub(add_closing_tag_search, add_closing_tag_replace, ffx)
```

but it only fixes one issue while causing another--`WEBSITE.COM` has disappeared and now `SubjectFullName` doesn't have a closing tag.

```
<Subject stype="ORG" xref="1234">
    <SubjectFullName type="L"><ENAMEX></ENAMEX>
    <SubjectLastName type="L">WEBSITE.COM</SubjectLastName>
    <SubjectPhone type="Work">1234567890</SubjectPhone>
</Subject>
```

Ultimately, I don't really need that `ENAMEX` tag so I'd like to just drop it from the xml only when it doesn't have an ending tag. My code does take care of removing the extraneous `ENAMEX` tag in `SubjectLastName`, but I'm struggling with the right regex to remove it from the `SubjectFullName` tag without also removing `WEBSITE.COM</SubjectFullName>`. I attempted to replace with `\1` but it obviously doesn't work and just leaves behind that weird square symbol. Ultimately, I would like to end up with

```
<Subject stype="ORG" xref="1234">
    <SubjectFullName type="L">WEBSITE.COM</SubjectFullName>
    <SubjectLastName type="L">WEBSITE.COM</SubjectLastName>
    <SubjectPhone type="Work">1234567890</SubjectPhone>
</Subject>
```

Comment: This might quite possibly be the only legitimate use of regex against XML that I've seen in quite some time.

Comment: Maybe just `re.sub(r'</?ENAMEX(?:\s[^>]*)?>', '', text)` will do?